# How can I store/get big data made of strings and typedArray(audio/video) into/from indexeddb

Tags: javascript, local-storage, blob, indexeddb

I am storing the mixture of strings and binary data by series wise in indexedDb, Something like

```
var mainData = [
    {d : string},
    {d : string},
    {d : typedArray},
    {d : typedArray},
    {d : typedArray},
    {d : string},
    {d : string}
];
```

Now I need to convert this data into blob file from **indexedDb**,  and let the user download this file.

From this exported file, I need the complete data in it's orginial format.

**Stringify way**

If I convert these data into blob file as **JSON** by something like

```
var myblob = new Blob([stringifyData], {type: "application/json"});
```

The size of file would be very large which is not useful for my case.

**typedArray way**

I can not convert this data into blob file as **typedArray**, something like

```
var myblob = new Blob(mainData,  {type: 'application/octet-binary'}
```

This does not work, because there is mixuture data of string and typed array in indexedDb.

And **mainData** is expected to be an array(typedArray) of values not array of objects.

**So my questions are**

1. How do export the mixture data(string and binary) from indexDb as blob file for later use these data in it's orginal format.
2. Is there any way(can be other client side storage also) by which I can meet my requirement?

Comment: You appear to be asking two different questions:

(1) How do I read saved data from Indexed DB (or another storage API) into a live JS data structure
(2) How do I efficiently serialize a live JS data structure into a Blob/File, and later deserialize the Blob/File back into a live JS data structure

It's not clear if you're having problems with #1, but solving #2 is going to be more difficult if you're conflating them.